# LIKE comparison of a different kind

Tags: regex, excel, vba

### Background

I am working on a game analysis software where I have to convert sentences into what I call "sentence templates" and match those sentence templates with standard templates which are stored in an Excel sheet. Based on whether a match is found or not found there are some actions to be taken. The whole program is in an Excel-VBA.

For example, if the sentence is:

Pass thrown left flat T.Harry closest defender

The corresponding sentence template is:

Pass thrown $DIR$ flat $NAME$ closest defender

Thus the sentence template replaces "variable" words in a sentence with what I call "Masks". Thus $DIR$ could represent either of "left", "right" or "center" and it will still represent the same sentence template. Similarly G.Jones could replace T.Harry and it would still be the same template.

Other than $DIR$ and $NAME$ there are about half a dozen different types of masks that are used. There are about 1200 standard templates.

### Problem:

The masking is done through a program that cannot be 100 % foolproof because the words masked, particularly the names, have many variations. For Example, T.Harry can be referred to simply as Harry or T. Harry(with space in between) or Tom Harry. I need to have some way of determining that if all the other words in the sentence match the words of any of the 1200 templates except for the masks. If this "LIKE" match occurs, it is most likely the same sentence template and provided certain other filter conditions are met, it can be taken as the same sentence template with high degree of confidence.

The Masks can appear at any position in the sentence and do not have any fixed places.

My Approach (which I think is inefficient and is brute force)

a) Split each of the 1200 standard sentence templates into words using Split function

b) Split the sentence to be compared also into words using Split function

c) Match the words in "b" with each of the 1200 templates in a loop by using following logic

d) Keep matching words in the sentence template with the words from the standard sentence templates till one word does not match. If a word does not match, skip that and proceed to the next word. Keep matching till the non matching words exceed the number of masks.

e) If non matching words exceed the number of masks it is most likely not same sentence.

f) If non matching words are equal to or less than the number of masks and except for the masks, all other words match, then with a high degree of confidence it is the same sentence template.

Is there a better way to do this? Are there ways we can find which is the first character where two strings do not match or show divergence.

Help appreciated. As of now I have sought manual intervention when sentences do not match but if the above logic works, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using regular expressions with your templates (e.g. `^Pass thrown .*? flat .*? closest defender$`) and then running through these within the VBA...
You can use regular expressions in VBA like this (example function):

```
Function RegExpTest(ByVal repattern As String, ByVal value As String)
 ' does a regular expression search for "repattern" in string "value"
 ' returns the match
 '  or "" if not found

  Dim RegEx As Object
  ' create the RegExp Object with late binding
  Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  With RegEx
    .Global = True      'look for global matches
    .Pattern = repattern
  End With
  RegExpTest = RegEx.Test(value)
  Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

It is still not going to break any speed records, but simpler and quicker than the splitting approach (particularly where names could have spaces in - the regex will deal with that fine)

**EDIT**
In the example function, the `repattern` is a string passed in (e.g. from a worksheet function call). The `repattern` can equally be set as the value of a cell - i.e. your patterns stored in cells in your worksheet.
So, for each input string, you could loop over your worksheet range containing the regular expression pattern and test the string for a match, breaking out of the loop if a match is found.

In terms of making the patterns from your templates, if all of your masks follow the format `$SOMETHING$` you could use regular expressions to make substitutions to make your templates into patterns :-) With the function below in your VBA, in your worksheet you would put the formula `=REGSUB("\$.*?\$",A1,".*?")`! Enjoy!

```
Function RegSub(ByVal repattern As String, ByVal value As String, ByVal replacement As String) As String
  RegSub = value
  Dim RegEx As Object
  Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  With RegEx
    .Global = True      'look for global matches -> replace all
    .Pattern = repattern
  End With
  RegSub = RegEx.Replace(value, replacement)
  Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: This seems to be very useful. But can you please elaborate

Comment: Hi @Peekay - which bit needs elaboration!

Comment: Hi @Captain Thank you for your continued interest. If I have to write/hard code for each template, it may not be very useful as I keep updating the 1200 odd standard templates in an excel column. That is where I am not sure how to go forward with this. Nevertheless, a great suggestion. If you think there is a way to keep the standard sentence templates in a column and use regular expressions to match the found templates with the standard templates without hardcoding please let me know and I will research this further.

Comment: Hi @Peekay, did the information in the edit clear things up for you?